# turtlebot3_teleop_keyboard-1 process has died

Tags: ros

roslaunch turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch
After running roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_empty_world.launch I try to launch roslaunch        turtlebot3_teleop turtlebot3_teleop_key.launch which shows the error message

```
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://jainvrushab5-Aspire-A515-57G:41223/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /model: waffle_pi
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.15

NODES
  /
    turtlebot3_teleop_keyboard (turtlebot3_teleop/turtlebot3_teleop_key)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[turtlebot3_teleop_keyboard-1]: started with pid [6660]`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jainvrushab5/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlebot3_teleop/turtlebot3_teleop_key", line 7, in <module>
    with open(python_script, 'r') as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/jainvrushab5/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_teleop/nodes/turtlebot3_teleop_key.py'
[turtlebot3_teleop_keyboard-1] process has died [pid 6660, exit code 1, cmd /home/jainvrushab5/catkin_ws/devel/lib/turtlebot3_teleop/turtlebot3_teleop_key __name:=turtlebot3_teleop_keyboard __log:=/home/jainvrushab5/.ros/log/1773e990-b8f8-11ed-a4dd-db1d229276aa/turtlebot3_teleop_keyboard-1.log].
log file: /home/jainvrushab5/.ros/log/1773e990-b8f8-11ed-a4dd-db1d229276aa/turtlebot3_teleop_keyboard-1*.log
all processes on machine have died, roslaunch will exit
shutting down processing monitor...
... shutting down processing monitor complete

done``


turtlebot3_teleop_key file.py details

    `#!/usr/bin/python3
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    # generated from catkin/cmake/template/script.py.in
    # creates a relay to a python script source file, acting as that file.
    # The purpose is that of a symlink
    python_script = '/home/jainvrushab5/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_teleop/nodes/turtlebot3_teleop_key'
    with open(python_script, 'r') as fh:
        context = {
            '__builtins__': __builtins__,
            '__doc__': None,
            '__file__': python_script,
            '__name__': __name__,
            '__package__': None,
        }
        exec(compile(fh.read(), python_script, 'exec'), context)`
```

Comment: Can you also please post both the launch files? It is unclear what all nodes both of the files are launching.

Comment: I would check if this file exist and does it have execute permission (chmod +x filename) `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/jainvrushab5/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_teleop/nodes/turtlebot3_teleop_key.py'`
Or I would reinstall this package and check same things